# very basic set theory ? about the Pairing Axiom over multiple sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm going through a text<sup>1</sup> right now that's laying out basic set axioms. It describes/defines the Pairing Axiom, and then gives the following example:

**"Given three sets u, v, and w". The pairing axiom yields the sets {u, v}, {{u, v}, w}, {{u, v}, {w}}.**

I think that this list is meant to be exhaustive. *But aren't there other sets also* generated on u,v,w by the Pairing axiom? Specifically - what about $\{v,w\}$, $\{u, \{v, w\}\}$, or $\{\{u\}, \{v,w\}\}$ for example?

I feel like I'm missing something obvious and found no answer elsewhere, thanking you in advance for any thoughts

<sup>1</sup>Daniel W. Cunningham: *Set Theory: A First Course*, [page 32](https://books.google.com/books?id=S1GJDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA32)

Comment: It's probably a good idea to also provide the source of this.

Comment: "Set Theory" A First Course.  Daniel W. Cunningham, pg. 32

Answer (score 4):

This list is not meant to be exhaustive.  It is just a few examples of sets that you can create from $u,v,$ and $w$ by repeatedly using the Axiom of Pairing.

Comment: that was my hope.  thanks